# C# using library with awaitable async methods in Unity without locking the main thread

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, task, coroutine

I have a script like this:

```
public class Example : Monobehaviour
{
    public async void Start()
    {
        LibraryClass service = new LibraryClass();

        bool result = await service.Login();
        if (result == false)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Login Failed !!");
            return;
        }

        result = await service.Load();
        if (result == false)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Load Failed !!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The signatures for the LibraryClass methods are something like:

```
public async Task<bool> Login();
```

and

```
public async Task<bool> Load();
```

When running the script, the main thread of Unity was blocked and I had to wait a long time before all the operations were completed.
I decided to add a progress bar, but, of course, nothing was going to be updated until the very end of the execution of the 2 methods.
I decided to change the script to something like this:

```
public class Example : Monobehaviour
{
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        LibraryClass service = new LibraryClass();
        WaitForEndOfFrame wait = new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Task<bool> task = service.Login();
        while (task.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            yield return wait;
        }
    
        if (task.Result == false)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Login Failed !!");
            return;
        }

        task = service.Load();
        while (task.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            yield return wait;
        }
    
        if (task.Result == false)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Load Failed !!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed an improvement but the main thread will still be blocked and stop the update of the UI and the rest of the game because, I think, the library internally is using several different awaits on different operations (HTTP request, loading zip files content, etc...) which I have no control of because fired by those 2 public methods I am using.

Is there somehow a way to avoid the main thread of Unity to be completely blocked?

Comment: `await` doesn't lock the calling thread. That's the whole point. `await` doesn't start an asynchronous operation, it  *awaits* an already active task. The calling thread is released to do other work, eg the UI thread can go back to updating the UI and handling events. When the task completes, execution resumes after `await`

Comment: I'd strongly recommend [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask)

Comment: What do `Login` and `Load` actually do? Do they perform true asynchronous work or are they synchronous methods with an `async Task` return type? `async` doesn't make a method asynchronous either. Execution will complete synchronously until the first `await trueAsyncOperation();` call, eg a network call

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not entirely sure of the implementation of the Login and Load methods. I just suppose they may call other async operation by using awaits internally. I suppose Login may call an await on an HttpClient but I don't have access to the library source code.

Comment: @derHugo thanks for the suggestion: I will take a look  :)

Comment: You can also keep track of the progress in the update function or anything you change in async func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asynchronous method signature indicates that the method *may* be asynchronous, not that it *must* be asynchronous. From the observed behavior, it seems that the method is (at least partially) synchronous.

Since you're writing a UI application, an appropriate workaround is to wrap blocking methods in a `Task.Run` (i.e., run them on the thread pool). E.g.:

```
public class Example : Monobehaviour
{
    public async void Start()
    {
        LibraryClass service = new LibraryClass();

        bool result = await Task.Run(() => service.Login());
        if (result == false)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Login Failed !!");
            return;
        }

        result = await Task.Run(() => service.Load());
        if (result == false)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Load Failed !!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I still have some issue in understanding tasks, although, I admit your solution is more elegant than mine involving threads because it won't have the issue of needing to sync the results of the tasks with the Unity lifecycle. Thank you for sharing  :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, everyone, this is my solution: I encapsulated the Task in a Thread, I run the Thread and wait for the Thread.
This solution results in silky smooth performances that don't even have stutters.
Here's the example code changed:

```
public class Example : Monobehaviour
{
    private bool _threadRunning = false;

    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        LibraryClass service = new LibraryClass();
        WaitForEndOfFrame wait = new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => { LoginThreadWorker(service); });
        thread.Start();
        _threadRunning = true;
    
        while (_threadRunning)
        {
            yield return wait;
        }

        thread = new Thread(() => { LoginThreadWorker(service); });
        thread.Start();
        _threadRunning = true;
    
        while (_threadRunning)
        {
            yield return wait;
        }
    }

    private void LoginThreadWorker(LibraryClass service)
    {
        Task<bool> task = service.Login();
        task.Wait();
    
        if (task.Result == false)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Login Failed !!");
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO - successfully logged in.
        }
    
        _threadRunning = false;
    }

    private void LoadThreadWorker(LibraryClass service)
    {
        Task<bool> task = service.Load();
        task.Wait();
    
        if (task.Result == false)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Load Failed !!");
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO - successfully loaded.
        }
    
        _threadRunning = false;
    }
}
```

So, basically the System.Threading.Task that was blocking the Unity's main thread is now encapsulated in a System.Threading.Thread that is encapsulated in a Coroutine.
Maybe this is not the most elegant solution but it works for me, so, I decided to share it here as well.

**PLEASE NOTE:** this works **ONLY** because the System.Threading.Task methods I have from the library **DON'T** need to change directly any UnityEngine object. If your tasks are interacting with anything from the engine, then this kind of operation is not suitable for you because you cannot change UnityEngine objects from outside the Unity's main thread.